# Sql to get join path relations in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

What is the equivalent of the following query in snowflake? This works on mysql and postgresql.

```
SELECT
   CONSTRAINT_NAME as name,
   TABLE_NAME as parent_table,
   COLUMN_NAME as parent_column,
   REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME as referenced_table,
   REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME as referenced_column
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
   where table_schema = 'public'
   and REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME is not null
```

How do I get the same info on snowflake i.e all existing paths between tables?

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by “all existing paths between tables”? Do you just want to list the foreign keys that have been defined?

Comment: Hi, I mean a query to retrieve all the foreign key constraints, including the schema, table, and column names for both the foreign key and the referenced key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA     as fk_schema,

```
   tc_parent.table_name      as parent_table,

   tc_child.table_name       as child_table,

   rc.constraint_name        as child_fk_name,

   rc.unique_constraint_name as parent_constraint_name,

    tc_parent.constraint_type as parent_constraint_type,

   rc.created                as fk_created

from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc

  -- ---------------------------------------------------

join information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc_parent

  on rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc_parent.CONSTRAINT_NAME

 and rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = tc_parent.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA

     -- ---------------------------------------------------

join information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc_child

  on rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc_child.CONSTRAINT_NAME

 and rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = tc_child.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
```

;

--try this as per https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00006w5kwfSAA/how-do-you-get-the-column-names-for-a-foreign-key-constraint

Answer (score 0):

You can get that information by doing a query like this:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC';
```

but be aware that while Snowflake supports defining and maintaining constraints, it does not enforce them, except for NOT NULL constraints, which are always enforced.
This is further documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints).

Comment: This only lists the primary keys. I'm trying to get the foreign keys and the tables they connect.